# How to make update a few rows in the table one minimalnym number of database queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Have a collection of categories, represented as collections of objects. Each object has a sort property. This property takes a numeric value from 1 to the number which is the last element of the collection. There is a list of categories filtered by the sort property

```
linecategories=Linecategory.eager_load(:main_image).order('sort')
```

Then this list is dragged drag and drap and a certain number of objects to the collection is changing the value of this property sort. Further ajax goes from 2 to n of objects whose properties of the sort has changed.
Task to do update the changed fields in the database.
Now data comes in the form of:

```
data={}
data['items']=params[:data]
```

Where data has the form

```
data: [{id: 1, name: "Гороскопы", slug: "horoscopes", title: "keywords-horoscopes",…},…]
0: {id: 1, name: "Гороскопы", slug: "horoscopes", title: "keywords-horoscopes",…}
created_at: "2015-01-10T21:14:56.000Z"
description: "description-horoscopes"
id: 1
keywords: "keywords-horoscopes"
name: "Гороскопы"
slug: "horoscopes"
sort: 1
title: "keywords-horoscopes"
updated_at: "2015-07-19T19:10:03.000Z"
1: {id: 5, name: "Гадания", slug: "divination", title: "eywords-divination",…}
created_at: "2015-01-11T08:47:10.000Z"
description: "2015-01-11 08:47:10"
id: 5
keywords: "description-divination"
main_image: {id: 1, src: "images/categories_images/devination.jpg", linecategory_id: 5, created_at: null,…}
name: "Гадания"
slug: "divination"
sort: 2
title: "eywords-divination"
updated_at: "2015-07-19T19:24:23.000Z"
2: {id: 3, name: "Вкусности", slug: "delicious", title: "keywords-delicious",…}
created_at: "2015-01-10T21:17:28.000Z"
description: "2015-01-10 21:17:28"
id: 3
keywords: "description-delicious"
name: "Вкусности"
slug: "delicious"
sort: 3
title: "keywords-delicious"
updated_at: "2015-07-19T19:24:23.000Z"
```

Now I implemented the update like so:

```
def updates
    data={}
    data['items']=params[:data]
    data['items'].each { |el|
      @item=Linecategory.find(el['id'])
      @item.update_attributes(el.permit(:sort))
    }
    render json: {update: 1, data: data['items']}
  end
```

But I think it is not the optimal solution, I think it can be done more efficiently and more beautiful by means of ruby on rails and activerecords whether this is so, and if possible suggest solutions to the problem?

Comment: Duh. I read the question twice and I still don't understand what needs to be done. Maybe [this](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list) will help? It already has an operation "insert at position" that does 2 queries regardless of the size of the list (effectively O(1)).

Comment: I want update multiple rows with one query, but now I have a lot of requests to update the database. I think it is not the optimal solution.
# Updates one record
Person.update(15, user_name: 'Samuel', group: 'expert')

# Updates multiple records
people = { 1 => { "first_name" => "David" }, 2 => { "first_name" => "Jeremy" } }
Person.update(people.keys, people.values)

Comment: about I would like something like this:
data=params[:data]
# data=[{"id"=>1,"sort":2},[{"id"=>5,"sort":7}]
Linecategory.update(data)
I.e. to transmit the modified collection of objects, and coversite their update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found better method

```
# /admin_categories PUT
  def updates
    data=params[:data].as_json(only: [:id, :sort])
    db = ActiveRecord::Base.connection()
    ids=[]
    query = "UPDATE linecategories SET sort = CASE id "
    data.each_with_index do |e, i|
      query += ActiveRecord::Base.send(:sanitize_sql_array,["WHEN ? THEN ? ", e['id'], e['sort']])
      ids.push e['id']
    end
    query += "END "
    query += "WHERE id in (#{ids.join(",")}) "
    db.execute(query)
    render json: {}
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  def updates
    data=params[:data].as_json(only: [:id, :sort])
    h = {}
    data.each_with_index { |e, i| h[e['id']] = e }
    Linecategory.update(h.keys, h.values)
    render json: {update: 1, data: h}
  end
```

Mine has found solutions, I still don't katsa completely optimal, since before the update I have to use:
data.each_with_index { |e, i| h[e['id']] = e }
but even so it works.
Plausible queries to update the database continues to be set, but girlfriend can do it?

```
 Linecategory Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `linecategories`.* FROM `linecategories`  WHERE `linecategories`.`id` = 6 LIMIT 1
       (0.3ms)  BEGIN
      Linecategory Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `linecategories`  WHERE (`linecategories`.`slug` = BINARY 'our_dreams' AND `linecategories`.`id` != 6) LIMIT 1
      SQL (0.2ms)  UPDATE `linecategories` SET `sort` = 1, `updated_at` = '2015-07-20 21:07:47' WHERE `linecategories`.`id` = 6
       (2.3ms)  COMMIT
      Linecategory Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `linecategories`.* FROM `linecategories`  WHERE `linecategories`.`id` = 4 LIMIT 1
       (0.3ms)  BEGIN
      Linecategory Exists (0.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `linecategories`  WHERE (`linecategories`.`slug` = BINARY 'beauty_and_health' AND `linecategories`.`id` != 4) LIMIT 1
      SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE `linecategories` SET `sort` = 2, `updated_at` = '2015-07-20 21:07:47' WHERE `linecategories`.`id` = 4
       (1.0ms)  COMMIT
      Linecategory Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `linecategories`.* FROM `linecategories`  WHERE `linecategories`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
       (0.2ms)  BEGIN
      Linecategory Exists (0.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `linecategories`  WHERE (`linecategories`.`slug` = BINARY 'horoscopes' AND `linecategories`.`id` != 1) LIMIT 1
      SQL (0.2ms)  UPDATE `linecategories` SET `sort` = 3, `updated_at` = '2015-07-20 21:07:47' WHERE `linecategories`.`id` = 1
       (0.9ms)  COMMIT
      Linecategory Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `linecategories`.* FROM `linecategories`  WHERE `linecategories`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1
       (0.3ms)  BEGIN
      Linecategory Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `linecategories`  WHERE (`linecategories`.`slug` = BINARY 'test_yourself' AND `linecategories`.`id` != 2) LIMIT 1
      SQL (0.5ms)  UPDATE `linecategories` SET `sort` = 4, `updated_at` = '2015-07-20 21:07:48' WHERE `linecategories`.`id` = 2
       (0.9ms)  COMMIT
      Linecategory Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `linecategories`.* FROM `linecategories`  WHERE `linecategories`.`id` = 5 LIMIT 1
       (0.2ms)  BEGIN
      Linecategory Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `linecategories`  WHERE (`linecategories`.`slug` = BINARY 'divination' AND `linecategories`.`id` != 5) LIMIT 1
      SQL (0.2ms)  UPDATE `linecategories` SET `sort` = 5, `updated_at` = '2015-07-20 21:07:48' WHERE `linecategories`.`id` = 5
       (0.8ms)  COMMIT
      Linecategory Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `linecategories`.* FROM `linecategories`  WHERE `linecategories`.`id` = 7 LIMIT 1
       (0.1ms)  BEGIN
      Linecategory Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `linecategories`  WHERE (`linecategories`.`slug` = BINARY 'what_is_it_in_my_name' AND `linecategories`.`id` != 7) LIMIT 1
      SQL (0.2ms)  UPDATE `linecategories` SET `sort` = 6, `updated_at` = '2015-07-20 21:07:48' WHERE `linecategories`.`id` = 7
       (0.9ms)  COMMIT
      Linecategory Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `linecategories`.* FROM `linecategories`  WHERE `linecategories`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 1
       (0.2ms)  BEGIN
      Linecategory Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `linecategories`  WHERE (`linecategories`.`slug` = BINARY 'delicious' AND `linecategories`.`id` != 3) LIMIT 1
      SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE `linecategories` SET `sort` = 7, `updated_at` = '2015-07-20 21:07:48' WHERE `linecategories`.`id` = 3
       (1.0ms)  COMMIT
```